# Symfony 2.3 handleRequest($request) doesn't set entity

Tags: php, validation, symfony

I have contact Entity, making post call using:

```
postContactAction(Request $request)
```

Generated form using `app/console generate:doctrine:form BundleName:Contact`

In post function trying to get request and set entity to request parameters like name, email and etc:

```
$contact = new Contact();
$form = $this->createForm(new ContactType(), $contact, array(
    'method' => 'POST'));
$form->handleRequest($request);
```

And while checking, `var_dump($contact);` returns fields with null value.

What can be the problem?

Using postman to send post request and it worked without form.

In ContactType:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name', 'text')
            ->add('email', 'text', array('required' => false))
            ->add('phone', 'integer', array('required' => false))
            ->add('text', 'textarea')
            ->add('subject', 'text')
            ->add('createdAt', 'datetime', array('required' => false))
        ;
    }
```

In ContactController:

```
public function postContactAction(Request $request)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $this->initErrorContainer();
        $validator = $this->get('validator');

        $contactDetails = $this->getRequest()->request->all();

        // check if email and phone exists or not. One is enough
        if (!array_key_exists('email', $contactDetails) && !array_key_exists('phone', $contactDetails)) {
            $this->errorContainer->createAndAdd('email', $this->errorContainer->MESSAGE_REQUIRED);
            $this->errorContainer->createAndAdd('phone', $this->errorContainer->MESSAGE_REQUIRED);
            return $this->getView();
        }

        $contact = new Contact();

        // handle form
        $form = $this->createForm(new ContactType(), $contact, array(
            'method' => 'POST'));
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        // set default values
        var_dump($contact);
        die;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. As Entity uses different types than request, you need to create simply model of this entity, set request fields to that entity type using handleRequest, and then you can use it.

Answer (score 0):

Is weird, but can you try to get the form after call createForm to see if that has something related, namely:
you have:

```
$form = $this->createForm(new ContactType(), $contact, array('method' => 'POST'));
```

Then just add:

```
$form = $this->createForm(new ContactType(), $contact, array('method' => 'POST'))->getForm();
```

Comment: Error: Call to undefined method Symfony\Component\Form\Form::getForm()

Comment: Can you stick the Action and the ContactType class?

Comment: Wrap the var_dump into an if to print it only when is a post resquest: If ($request->getMethod() === 'POST')  {var_dump($contact)} die();

Comment: same thing. The request already was POST as it is post method, otherwise symfony will give method error.

Comment: Ok, so you are using thia action only for post request... Can you do a var_dump($request)?

Comment: did it, request is ok, thats how I'm checking email and phone